# How to use FromForm attribute in ASP.NET Web API 5.2.3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have created a brand new project in VS 2017 - by using the Web API template. But I am not able to use `[FromForm]` attribute in the controller action method.

Here some lines from package.config:

```
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
```

Is the `[FromForm]` available in Web API version 5.2.3?

**If not then how to read FormData values?**

Code:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("v1/users/register")]
public void RegisterUser(FormDataCollection formData)
{
    var fName = formData["firsName"]; // formData is NULL
}
```

Postman request:

[image]

Comment: FromForm attribute  intends to asp core. You cannot use it in .net web api project.

Comment: Then how I can read FormData in Web API 5.2.3?

Comment: You look at https://books.google.co.il/books?id=7aE8BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA11&lpg=PA11&dq=web+api+2+public+string+Post(FormDataCollection+form)&source=bl&ots=fwZ1LXTyRD&sig=ACfU3U2rt5RqAeDIgmqwn3Koo1fJl8pVJw&hl=iw&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjMoMvivYXlAhUS16QKHfBJApYQ6AEwB3oECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=web%20api%202%20public%20string%20Post(FormDataCollection%20form)&f=false

Comment: @Oleg you mean FormValueCollection will do the work?

Comment: Yes, you can also try do it with model as parameter without any model binding  attributes.

Comment: @Oleg Getting null - What should be the content-type for the request?

Comment: Can you post your client request and server action

Comment: @Oleg Added please check + when I set content type - application/json it show's `null`

Comment: Did you try with encoding type form-urlencoded?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200447/discussion-between-oleg-and-prashant-pimpale).

Comment: @Oleg you can post an answer, will mark it as a answer!

Comment: I added answer, you can also add input  parameter :HttpRequest request and retreive all you need without httpcontext call  and get HttpContext.Request through it. I mean RegisterUser(HttpRequest request) and request.Form

Comment: I just used the [FromForm] attribute to [solve one of my own problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74352005/c-sharp-file-upload-web-method-not-accepting-form-data-sent-along-with-uploaded).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get form data from

HttpContext.Current.Request.Form: key and value.

Files: HttpContext.Request.Form.Files.

Post action must be without input or can be with HttpRequest parameter, like:

RegisterUser(HttpRequest request) and request.Form....

Comment: Can we bind model with `Request.Form`